# Can't open a link as a background tab - Java, Selenium, IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, automation

So of course in internet explorer (9) I cannot get a link to open in a background tab. I've tried a few things :

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
driver.findElement(By.name(THE_LINK)).click();
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

I've also tried

```
String link = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
driver.findElement(By.name(THE_LINK)).sendKeys(link);
```

It actually opens it in a new window.

When I'm working manually and ctrl+click it works as expected and opens in a background tab. I've tried resetting browser settings and doing a lot of different things but of course, it doesn't work as expected.

Anyone seen this before? Anyone got a different thing for me to try?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do this.

If you click the link, just switch back to the original context by using:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

to get back to the tab you were on.

If that doesn't work, you might have to do

```
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles()[0]);  // i'm not at my programming computer so i can't remember the actual syntax ;)
```

Comment: tread lightly. explain that that functionality is per the browser. unless you are testing a browser, there is no reason to do this. Selenium tests the web application. not the browser `;)`

Comment: it's also important to know, that Selenium doesn't know (and doesn't care) about the difference between windows and tabs.

Comment: The problem is that manually the browser functions correctly. Why would it change because I'm using selenium? The robot class functions the same manner as it would manually, no?

Comment: It would change because IE has a driver built around WebDriver.  Their implementation *might* not be the same as it would be manually. so it could produce different results. frustrating i know