# python selenium, open link in new tab without navigating to it

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium to do web scraping and I'm trying to use a link to open a tab, whilst staying on the original tab. I have the following:

```
first_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
```

which is meant to open the tab and navigate to it, but it just opens up the link in the original tab. Is there any way to open the link in a new tab, and furthermore, not navigate to it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16180428/954442, http://stackoverflow.com/q/30406431/954442, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27628386/954442

Comment: @AndrewRegan Those deal with either opening a new tab or switching between opened tabs. Doesn't answer his question to actively 'open a link in a new tab and in background'.

Comment: I disagree, but OP's can decide what best works for him.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid switching to the new tab. You may want to set `browser.tabs.loadInBackground` to `true` (although that is the default).

Use `Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ENTER` (and not `Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN`).
On Mac, it should be `Keys.COMMAND + Keys.ENTER`.

After that, to deal with switching between tabs and windows, check out these SO questions:

- [Selenium multiple tabs at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18150682/1431750)
- [switch tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944233/1431750)